# Where to ask about a Vietnamese correct translation

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Where would it be best to ask about the correct translation of a Vietnamse word?

I seen a few Vietnamese-related questions on the [linguistic sub-SE](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/) but I feel like linguistic is meant for broader type of question. (Or does the linguistic sub-SE acts as a fallback for all non-existent dedicated sub-SE to a specific language?)

More specifically, my question was what is the proper translation of làm: Is it "to do" or "to make"?

As per usual, Google didn't help out much so here I ask.

Comment: I don't think that SE is generally a good place for translation help. Have you tried consulting a Vietnamese-English dictionary?

Comment: @Catija None really helped as hoped.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question doesn't seem to be suited to any currently existing Stack Exchange site. The Linguistics [on-topic page](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) explicitly rejects translation requests. I consulted the list of Stack Exchange sites, specifically the ["culture and recreation" category](https://stackexchange.com/sites#culturerecreation), and there is no Vietnamese language site or a generic translation site.

Interestingly enough, somebody *super recently* proposed a [Vietnamese Language site at Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/93764/vietnamese-language?referrer=iZ8INaoX5bU6NN-R9Al6mw2).

Aside: the answer to your proposed question is "both!" That word is like the Spanish [*hacer*](http://www.spanishdict.com/examples/hacer), in my understanding. The English translation depends on context.

Comment: Oops, you were a few seconds quicker than me ;-) ...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ now that is interesting. 6 hours nobody answered, then 2 in the same minute.

Answer (score 2):

Well, there's a brand new (just 2 from days ago now) proposal for a [Vietnamese Language](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/93764/vietnamese-language) site to be found at Area51.

This site would fit your question being on-topic I think.

Though there aren't any followers yet (besides the OP who proposed the site), and I have my doubts it will gain much of these quickly.

You can try posting your question as an example question at the current stage, if I understood correctly. Good luck.